# Finding the distribution of the sum of independent random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I cannot imagine that this has not been asked before, but the search function floods you with specific examples, so I cannot find it. The thing I want to prove is as follows:

Suppose $X, Y: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \to \mathbb{R}$ are independent random variables, let $Z = X + Y$. Denote $F_X, F_Y, F_Z$ for their distributions and $\mu_Y$ for the law of $Y$ (so $\mu_Y(B) = \mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}(B))$. What I want to show is

> $F_Z(z) = \int F_X(z - y) \mu_Y(dy)$

I basically have no idea on how to solve this.

The only way I can think of to use the independence is by noting that $\mathbb{P}(Z^{-1}(-\infty, z]) = \mathbb{P}\left((\langle X, Y \rangle)^{-1}(C)\right)$ where $C = +^{-1}((-\infty, z]) = \{(x, y) \ | \ x + y \leq z\}$. Now for rectangles $A \times B$ we have by independence that $\mathbb{P}\left((\langle X, Y \rangle)^{-1}(X \times Y)\right) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A)) \mathbb{P}(Y^{-1}(B))$, so if we can write $C$ as a suitable disjoint union of rectangles we may be able to do something with it.

Comment: HINT: set $W:=(X,Y)$, then $\Pr [Z\leqslant c]=\Pr [W\in A]$ for $A:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x+y\leqslant c\}$.

Comment: @Masacroso I tried that, your $c$ is my $z$ and your $A$ is my $C$, but I got stuck after that. Can you give another hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $X$ and $Y$ are independent then the distribution of $W:=(X,Y)$ is just the product of the distributions, that is: $F_W=F_X\cdot F_Y$, this means that
$$
\Pr [W\in A]=\int_{A}\mathop{}\!d F_W=\int_{A}\mathop{}\!d (F_X\cdot F_Y) \tag1
$$
In your case we have that $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x+y\leqslant c\}$, so
$$
\Pr [Z\leqslant c]=\Pr [W\in A]=\int_{A}d(F_X\cdot F_Y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{A}(x,y)\mathop{}\!d (F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y))\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{A}(x,y)\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\mathop{}\!d  F_Y(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{A}(x,y)\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\right)\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\tag2
$$
Now observe that for fixed $y$ we have that $\mathbf{1}_{A}(x,y)=1 \Leftrightarrow x+y\leqslant c \Leftrightarrow x\leqslant c-y$, so we have that
$$
\mathbf{1}_{A}(x,y)=\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}(y)\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty .c-y]}(x)\tag3
$$
Using (3) in (2) we finally find that
$$
\Pr [Z\leqslant c]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}(y)\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty ,c-y]}(x)\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\right)\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{(-\infty ,c-y]}\mathop{}\!d F_X(x)\right)\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}F_X(c-y)\mathop{}\!d F_Y(y)\tag4
$$
∎